# How is the tutorial tutorial05_visualize.ipynb visualized?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, flow-project

When I run the `tutorial05_iisuallize` on jupyter notebook, there is no interface or output, but the code doesn't report errors, so I want to know what interface should appear if `tutorial05_iisuallize` runs successfully. Is it going to appear `sumo-gui` interface? Will there be output similar to the following?

```
Average, std return: -252.53104274827967, 0.0
Average, std speed: 16.992726414007908, 0.0
Average, std outflow: 3195.0, 0.0
```

Comment: Hey, what's this file you're talking about?? Give us some context!

Comment: flow/tutorials/tutorial05_visualize.ipynb

Comment: What's flow??? Jupyter is used for a LOT of things

Comment: @LucasDurand Flow is project for RL and traffic control: https://flow-project.github.io. Jing has used the appropriate tag to ask a question

Comment: We have some improvements for the visualization tutorial on the branch 'tuto-visu' here: https://github.com/flow-project/flow/pull/635/files. This has not been merged yet with the code, but I think it can help you!